# Format date and text data from API

Tags: javascript, github

I am working with Github API and I am displaying the data from users. When the date is displayed I want it to only have the date **user.created_at** with DD/MM/YY and not the whole hour. Also when the user has no Biography **user.bio** the data appears as null, and I want it to display the text 'The user has no bio'. I have not figured out the way to do both things so if you could help me I would very much appreciate it

Here below the code:

```
const APIURL = 'https://api.github.com/users/'

const main = document.getElementById('main')

const form = document.getElementById('form')

const search = document.getElementById('search')

async function getUser(username){
try{
    const { data } = await axios(APIURL + username)
    createUserCard(data)
    getRepos(username)
}catch (err){
    if(err.response.status == 404){
        createErrorCard('No profile with this Username')
      }
  }
}

async function getRepos(username){
try{
    const { data } = await axios(APIURL + username + '/repos?sort=created')

    addReposToCard(data)
}catch (err){
    createErrorCard('Problem Fetching Repos')

   }
 }

function createUserCard(user){
const cardHTML = `
    <div class="card">
        <div>
            <img src="${user.avatar_url}" alt="${user.name}" class="avatar">
        </div>
        <div class="user-info">

            <div class="header">
            <h2>${user.name}</h2>
            <p class="date">Joined ${user.created_at}</p>
            </div>
            <p>@${user.login}</p>
            <p>${user.bio}</p>
            
            

            <ul>
                <div class="list">
                <li>${user.followers} </li>
                <li>${user.following} </li>
                <li>${user.public_repos} </li>
                
                </div>

                <div class="list-names">
                <strong>Followers</strong>
                
                <strong>Following</strong>
                
                <strong>Repos</strong>
                
                
                </div>
            
            
                
            </ul>
            
            <div class="additional-data">
            <p class="location"><img src="./img/location.svg" alt="Location" class="img" />  ${user.location} </p>
            <a href=${user.html_url} target="_blank"><img src="./img/link.svg" alt="Link" class="img" />${user.html_url}</a>
            </div>

            <div id="repos"></div>
        </div>
    </div>`

main.innerHTML = cardHTML
}


function createErrorCard(msg){
const cardHTML = `
    <div class="card">
        <h1>${msg}</h1>
    </div>
`
 main.innerHTML = cardHTML
}


function addReposToCard(repos){
const reposEl = document.getElementById('repos')

repos
    .slice(0, 5)
    .forEach(repo => {
        const repoEl = document.createElement('a')
        repoEl.classList.add('repo')
        repoEl.href = repo.html_url
        repoEl.target = '_black'
        repoEl.innerText = repo.name

        reposEl.appendChild(repoEl)
    })
}

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault()

const user = search.value

if(user){
    getUser(user)

    search.value = ''
}
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. in the case of user.bio you can use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

   ```
   (conditional)?value when conditional true: value when conditional false
   ```

   for example:

   ```
   ${(user.bio!="null")?user.bio:"The user has no bio"}
   ```

   or

   ```
   ${(user.bio!=null)?user.bio:"The user has no bio"}
   ```
2. in the case of date github helps us giving us a formated string that we can cast to a date using `new Date()` and  format it using `Date.prototype.toLocaleString()`

   ```
   ${(new Date(user.created_at)).toLocaleDateString()}
   ```

   in this case is not needed to pass parameters to `toLocaleDateString()` but I encourage you to read about this function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Comment: Thank you, i read about those articles and now I undertand how they behave. The code works perfectly now!!